# DataConverstionWarning with GridsearchCV in Sklearn

Tags: python-2.7, scikit-learn

I'm getting the following warning repeatedly when using GridsearchCV in Sklearn

"DataConversionWarning: Copying input dataframe for slicing."

I tried running some of the models separately outside of Gridsearch and didn't get any warnings. It also didn't prevent Gridsearch from finding a model.

I have 2 Questions:
1) What does this error mean?
2) What are the implications for my output, if any?

The relevant parts of the code are below:

```
df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(filepath, "Modeling_Set.csv")) #loads main data
keep_vars = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(filepath, "keep_vars.csv")) #loads a list of variables to keep from a CSV list

model_vars = keep_vars[keep_vars['keep']==1]['name'] #creates a list of vars to keep
modeling_df = df[model_vars] #creates the df with only keep vars
model_feature_vars = model_vars[:-1]    


#Splits test and train data
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(modeling_df[model_feature_vars], modeling_df['Segment'], test_size=0.30, random_state=42)

#sets up models
#Range of parameters for gridsearch with decision trees
max_depth = range(2,20,2)
min_samples_split = range(2,10,2)
features = range(2, len(X_train.columns))
#set up for decision trees with gridsearch
parametersDT ={'feature_selection__k':features,
            'feature_selection__score_func':(chi2, f_classif),
            'classification__criterion':('gini','entropy'),
            'classification__max_depth':max_depth, 
            'classification__min_samples_split':min_samples_split}
DT_with_K_Best = Pipeline([
('feature_selection', SelectKBest()),
('classification', DecisionTreeClassifier())
])

clf_DT = GridSearchCV(DT_with_K_Best, parametersDT, cv=10, verbose=2,    scoring='f1_weighted', n_jobs = -2)  
clf_DT.fit(X_train,y_train)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell it only means that the DataFrame you're using is copied before being fed to the model.

This shouldn't affect the training results. It's only an efficiency problem, unrelated to the performance of the classifier.

Comment: That's what I suspected, but just wanted to make sure. Thanks!